# How can I create textbox on click function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to create two text box and one select box on button click function, but as I am filling boxes created by one click and on another click all the filled details get vanished.

I want the detail as I fill to be able to post in database ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script>
            var counter=1;
            function generateRow() {
                var d=document.getElementById("div");
                d.innerHTML+="<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox"+counter+"' name='stop"+counter+"' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox"+counter+"' name='timing"+counter+"' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><strong>Select Route</strong><select id='ampm"+counter+"'name='ampm"+counter+"'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>";
                counter++;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <div id="div"></div>
            <p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>
            <p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using plain javascript or jquery?

Comment: ya no jquery jus simple JS

Comment: Why don't you put everything inside a `div` and set it invisible. So when you click the button, just copy and paste HTML inside the div

Comment: When you say all the details vanish, do you mean that the data is cleared or the elements themselves disappear?

Comment: @guruprasath my data is getting cleared

Comment: @DoanCuong can u shw me code what you are talking about ..?

Comment: Can you try returning false from the generateRow function and see if the data is still cleared?

Comment: There are couple of other things you should note. You have multiple elements with the same id in your dynamic markup. And one of the p tags doesnt have a corresponding end tag if I am not mistaken. IE might have problem with that kind of markup

Comment: @guruprasath can u plz correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this way

```
var temp ="'<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox"+counter+"' name='stop"+counter+"' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox"+counter+"' name='timing"+counter+"' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><strong>Select Route</strong><select id='ampm"+counter+"'name='ampm"+counter+"'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>'";

var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = temp;
var yourDiv = document.getElementById('div');
yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
```

hope it will work

Comment: add this logic in 'generateRow()' function and dont forget to ++ your counter

Comment: i hv posted something
this code is workiing fine on frnt end but as i am posting the form only 1 details ie of the very last input fields are getting posted but i want the value filled in all the created boxes to get posted

Comment: check name and ids of your elements, are they same? or different? is your counter logic works correctly?

Comment: although i hv incremented the counter ant the end of function

Comment: so you are saying server recives only 2 text box and 1 dropdown, right?

Comment: @muneebShabbie :yaa exactly the same is happening

Comment: can you post your server code? point where you retrieve these elements

Comment: Shabbir now its woking i had just made a mistake ... i was just increasing the id with the counter as i was doing with name :that was my mistake::)

Answer (score 0):

First get `d.innerHTML` into another variable and new html in another variable. Then concat both of them and save in `innerhtml`

However, you should be building with `insertBefore` or `appendChild` functionality instead of the simple `innerHTML`.